# App react-native-openalpr crashed on launch

Tags: android, react-native, openalpr

My app is running approximatly 2 seconds and crash... We have time to see the camera working and after nothing, we come back to the main menu on the smartphone. I use an android phone in order to run the package react-native-openalpr.

Comment: dose it give any log file ?

Comment: 02-26 13:48:41.488 26497 26529 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 13:48:41.488 26497 26529 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 13:48:41.490 26497 26529 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 13:48:42.046 26497 26528 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "ReactNativeALPR" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 13:48:44.457 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()

Comment: i try to do this tuto : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-openalpr

Comment: your log is not complete,provide complete log in update question

Answer (score 0):

02-26 13:47:29.786 26328 26328 D ReactNative:
ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()
02-26 13:48:41.094 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor() 
02-26 13:48:41.152 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
02-26 13:48:41.153 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
02-26 13:48:41.155 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
02-26 13:48:41.170 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
02-26 13:48:41.170 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
02-26 13:48:41.264 26497 26519 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
02-26 13:48:41.478 26497 26519 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
02-26 13:48:41.481 26497 26519 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
02-26 13:48:41.487 26497 26519 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
02-26 13:48:41.488 26497 26519 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
02-26 13:48:41.488 26497 26529 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
02-26 13:48:41.488 26497 26529 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
02-26 13:48:41.490 26497 26529 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
02-26 13:48:42.046 26497 26528 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "ReactNativeALPR" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. **DEV** === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
02-26 13:48:44.457 26497 26497 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()